# How to dynamically connect an abstract class to different databases for a single request in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

In our application, we have several models which need to connect to different external databases that hold the same tables and columns, but are each separate and cannot be unified.

Currently, the application runs on separate servers, in which each is connected only to a specific external database. However, these are 10+ servers, all serving the exact same application, with the only difference being the external database they connect to.

The goal is to have a single server running the application and have the application decide which database to query based on a certain parameter passed into the controller.

Our current approach is the following. We have an abstract class from which relevant models inherit, with a method to reconnect it to the specific database:

```
class AbstractRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true 

  def self.reconnect
    database = Thread.current[:database_name].constantize
    self.establish_connection database
  end
end
```

Then, we have every controller inherit from a controller class with a before_action that sets the current database name in Thread.current and calls that method:

```
class AccessController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_current_database

  private 
  
  def set_current_database
    Thread.current[:database_name] = current_user.database_name
    AbstractRecord.reconnect
  end
end
```

Each user has the information on which database they need to connect to, and so the application reconnects the database based on the current user.

This application also serves an API, with controllers inheriting from a similar controller that also reconnects the database based on the current API user.

We know all of the databases we need to connect to and keep them in yml files, and all of them are loaded into constants inside an initializer.

This approach works for the most part. Whenever a request is made, the database is successfully reconnected to the appropiate database, and the application functions as normal.

However, issues arise when a request is sent at the same time that another request is being processed, both in development and production:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool with 'AbstractRecord' found.)
```

This error is raised whenever any model that needs to query the AbstractRecord database does so after a new connection has been initiated in a different request.

Given enough time to finish, requests don't seem to interfere with each other and the database reconnections work fine.

It is my understanding that Rails handles requests on individual threads for each of them, and each thread uses a different database connection, which raises the question: Why is establish_connection causing other requests to lose their connection? Is there a major misunderstanding on how threads and database connections work in Rails in this case?

Back to the main question: How can I dynamically connect my models to a specific database during a single request in this version of Rails? Is this approach correct, or is there a more adequate solution?

Rails version: 5.2.4.3

Ruby version: 2.6.3p62

Answer (score 0):

@Joaquin for me this is clearly a case of multi-tenancy, where I must have a central database with a customer table and their respective database connection. There are some libraries that do this elegantly, with the [ar-octopus gem](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus).

In your case, there is a concorrency failure, as the key you are using in `Thread.current` is probably being used in two or more simultaneous executions. A change I would make would be to make your `Thread.current` key more specific as

```
Thread.current[:"#{current-table-name}_database_name"] = current_user.database_name
```

where the Person class would have the key `Thread.current[:"#{Person.table_name}_database_name"]`, but this approach is not a silver bullet and is certainly has flaws.

I suggest looking at [gem ar-octopus](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus), it will bring you many benefits.